How in PhpStorm to hide/show Git remarks?
How can I get PhpStorm to hide/show(maybe on some hot key) Git remarks in code editor, like :

PhpStorm 2024.1

Since PhpStorm is also an IDE by JetBrains, I assume that the setting are the same.

Go to Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints
Under "Code vision", uncheck "Code author"
Click "Apply" to save your change


